# R - changing values to labels permanently in labelled data

Tags: r, label, spss, r-haven

I have worked with `haven` and `sjlabelled` to try and work with data labels included on sav files.

Here is some example data (the real data is much larger with many more variables, values, labels, etc., and all values occur numerous times):

```
library(sjlabelled)
col1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
col2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
labels <- c("x", "y", "z")
df <- set_labels(df, col2, labels = labels)
```

I know I can use `as_label` to manipulate the data frame using labels, subsetting using these labels, etc. However, I want to replace the values with the labels because some functions/processes revert the data to values and drop the labels entirely. I haven't been able to pin down when this will occur.

Using the example data, I want the original data frame to end up as the following, but instead of defining a new data frame, to just overwrite the values with the labels:

```
col1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
col2 <- c("x", "y", "z") # these were the labels but are now the values
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_labels(x)[x]` approach can cause problems when not all labels are included as values in the dataset, or if all values are missing (which can happen in survey data).

`sjlabelled::read_spss` by default converts all atomic variables *with value labels* to factors. Given that these represent labelled categorical variables, it makes sense for the output variables to be returned as factors. All atomic variables without value labels are assumed to be continuous and return as is.

`sjlabelled::copy_labels` can be used to return value and variables labels when they have been dropped.

```r
library(sjlabelled)

# Create test data
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
  col2 = c(1, 2, 3),
  col3 = c(NA, NA, NA)
)

df <- set_labels(df, col2, col3, labels = c("0" = "w", "1" = "x", "2" = "y", "3" = "z")) |>
  var_labels(
    col1 = "Var 1",
    col2 = "Var 2",
    col3 = "var 3"
  )


## Function to convert labelled variables to normal r factors
labels_to_values <- function(x, ...) {
  
  if(!is.null(attr(x, "labels"))) {
    x <- factor(x, levels = attr(x, "labels"), labels = names(attr(x, "labels")))
  }
  
  return(x)
  
}

# This approach produces incorrect results / errors
lapply(df[, 2:3], \(x) get_labels(x)[x])
#> $col2
#> [1] "w" "x" "y"
#> 
#> $col3
#> [1] NA NA NA NA

# This approach returns expected results
df <- lapply(df, labels_to_values) |>
  data.frame() |>
  copy_labels(df)  

df
#>   col1 col2 col3
#> 1    a    x <NA>
#> 2    b    y <NA>
#> 3    c    z <NA>

str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ col1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
#>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Var 1"
#>  $ col2: Factor w/ 4 levels "w","x","y","z": 2 3 4
#>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Var 2"
#>   ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:4] 0 1 2 3
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "w" "x" "y" "z"
#>  $ col3: Factor w/ 4 levels "w","x","y","z": NA NA NA
#>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "var 3"
#>   ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:4] 0 1 2 3
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I do work with survey data in SPSS where values/labels are not always included in the data, causing the issue you mention. I don't quite follow your solution, however. Were I to import the data using ```sjlabelled::read_spss```, does an ```lapply``` solution with ```as.character```, followed by ```as.numeric``` for variables where the number represents itself rather than a code (e.g. age) a valid way to keep labels and numbers where they should be without causing them to shift if any are missing? I don't really want factors or labelled data type columns after applying the code, for now. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I realise this solution doesn't preserve column labels. How would I keep those here, or is this attempt a non-starter?

Comment: Thanks @DeeG. Sorry I wasn't clear. Only variables with value labels are converted to factors. My suggestion is that all categorical variables *should* be converted to factors, as that is essentially what they are. Replacing the underlying numeric codes (values) with the labels. Continuous variables without labels (eg. age), will be left unchanged as numeric variables by `sjlabelled::read_spss`. By default `sjlabelled::read_spss` adds column labels, and if they are dropped during editing the `sjlabelled::copy_labels` will reinstate them.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `get_labels`

```
df$col2 <- get_labels(df$col2)[df$col2]
```

-output

```
> df
  col1 col2
1    a    x
2    b    y
3    c    z
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a whole data frame in one go, while also keeping the labels attributed to the variable names?

Comment: @DeeG if all the columns are having labels.  you can also do `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) get_labels(x)[x])`

Comment: is there a way to do this such that it ignores columns that are not labelled? Also, this doesn't preserve the labels for the column headers (variables). Is there a way around this?

Comment: @DeeG Try `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(!is.null(attr(x, "labels"))) {x1 <- get_labels(x)[x]; attr(x1, "labels") <- attr(x, "labels"); x1})`

Comment: Value labels are recorded under the `labels` attribute, whereas *variable* labels are recorded under `label` (note the missing 's'). So to keep variable labels the above code needs to be `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(!is.null(attr(x, "labels"))) {x1 <- get_labels(x)[x]; attr(x1, "label") <- attr(x, "label"); x1})`